# Silent install installer with prerequisites

Tags: installation, installshield, prerequisites

Is there a way to install silently (/s) an InstallShield (non-MSI) installer that requires its own prerequisites?

In my case the prerequisite is Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable. Its UI popping once the parent installer runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nearest solution I could find was manipulating pre-requisite by extracting it from its parent. Similar to: http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2007/02/07/update-regarding-silent-install-of-the-vc-8-0-runtime-vcredist-packages.aspx

Answer (score 2):

(Assuming you're using an InstallShield 2010 InstallScript project with InstallShield prerequisites...)

InstallShield prerequisites allow you to specify a command line to be used when it is run silently. If the redistributable you need to run takes a parameter that makes it run silently (unfortunately not all redistributables do), specify this in the prerequisite's `Specify the command line for the application when the setup is running in silent mode` field. I don't know specifically whether the VC++ 2008 redistributable takes such an argument. If it does not, perhaps you could create an MSI project that uses the VC++ 2008 merge module, then install this MSI as a prerequisite silently.

[Specifying Command-Line Parameters for an InstallShield Prerequisite](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/robo/projects/installshield16helplib/SetupPrereqEditorCmdLine.htm)

Comment: VC++ redistributable does support silent mode, and also the parent installer that wraps it. But the here's the problem: the author of the main installer chose to run VC++ redistributable with full UI, no matter what switches it gets upon execution. Seems that doing extraction of the main EXE is my only choice, though not preferable.

Comment: Ah, yeah, my answer is geared towards someone writing the setup, not the unlucky fellow who receives one that was poorly written. For your scenario, perhaps you can pre-install the VC++ redistributable silently, then the InstallShield setup should detect this and skip its non-silent installation.

Answer (score 0):

```
msiexec /i vc_red.msi USING_EXUIH=1 /qn
```

[Source](http://www.appdeploy.com/packages/detail.asp?id=1627)